# links in tinyMce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce-4

I want to update description.I'm using TinyMCE but it changes links and br-s with paragraph.How can I  solve this problem?

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in videos">
                    <td>{{x.title}}</td>
                    <td class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="x.description | linky| nl2brLimited"  > </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `forced_root_block` value to `false`, that will fix `br-to-paragraph` problem.